# Android Facebook Login error - CONNECTION_FAILURE: TigonError

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am getting Facebook login error on some devices. I have already integrated Facebook login and logging-in  successfully in many devices.
The faceboook SDK is `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'`.
Error Screen-[image: facebook login]

Comment: check your internet connetion then

Go to Settings>Apps>All, select Facebook, and Clear Cache/Clear Data, then Force Stop. Now try opening it and log in again

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem on my `react-native` app. It turns out my phone is not currently connected to the Internet. Connect the device to the Internet again fixed this issue.